# Add tooltip to drop down list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip, title

I have this code:

```
sourApp = $("#Company_SourceApplication");
$.each(SourceApplication, function (i, value) {
    sourApp.append($("<option />").val(value.id_source_application).text(value.application_name));
});
```

Can I add a tooltip with id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, simple search on google:

https://forums.asp.net/t/1707538.aspx?DropDownList+ToolTip+on+mouse+over